# How to uncode all symbole in the php code

Tags: php, encode

I want to encode all symbole like `à é è ...` in my php code. Example :

```
à --> %C3%A0
é --> %C3%A9
è --> %C3%A8
```

An example in my code :

```
$Name = 'Teàst';
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' . $Name . )
```

The url need to be like this : `http://example.com/name/Te%C3%A0st` 
What i need to add to my code please ?

Comment: there's probably a function for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the urlencode function to translate the characters into characters you can use in a URL.

```
$Name = utf8_encode('Teàst');
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/name/' . urlencode($Name));
```

**Update** as you mentioned the encoding is ASCII and not UFT-8 you need to convert the encoding from ASCII to UFT-8 first by calling utf8_encode, I've updated the example to show this.

Comment: It's not the right encoder. The result is `te%E0st` and not `Te%C3%A0st`

Comment: Does `rawurlencode` encode work for you? Without knowing the encoding it is hard to say.

Comment: Same problem, thats didnt work. For the encoding i think it ASCII

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that will work for you.